# How to make Button with image same size as the other Buttons?

Tags: python, tkinter, button

In this short program for understanding, i have 2 buttons as you can see in the image, the first one starting from the top has an image of a Recycle Bin and the second one is a normal button with width = 4. After resizing the image with ImageTk, how can i make the first button the same size of the second? If i don't set width and height the first button is too small just the size of the image, and even changing the values of width and height matching them with the second button if i change resolution of my screen they are no more the same size. Please can you help me? I need to understand this for a bigger program, this the the code, obviously you can't run it because the image is saved in my computer but maybe you can use on other image for test it.

[image]

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from ctypes import windll
windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)
win = Tk()
win.geometry('500x400')
immagine_cancella = Image.open('cestino2.png')
immagine_cancella = immagine_cancella.resize((33, 39))
immagine_cancella = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=immagine_cancella)
button1 = Button(win,image=immagine_cancella,width=75,height=62.495,bg='#008BC7',relief='solid',activebackground="#00A1E6")
button1.pack(pady= 50)

button2 = Button(win,text='9',font=('Ink Free',19),width=4,bg='#008BC7',relief='solid',activebackground="#00A1E6")
button2.pack(side=TOP)
win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
import tkinter as tk
#from PIL import Image, ImageTk
#from ctypes import windll
#windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)

win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry('500x400') 

#immagine_cancella = Image.open('cestino2.png')
#immagine_cancella = immagine_cancella.resize((33, 39))
#immagine_cancella = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=immagine_cancella)
 
 
button1 = tk.Button(win,font=('Ink Free',19), width=5,height=5,bg='#008BC7',relief='solid',activebackground="#00A1E6")
button1.pack()

button2 = tk.Button(win,text='9',font=('Ink Free',19), width=5,height=5,
                 bg='#008BC7',relief='solid',activebackground="#00A1E6")
button2.pack(side=tk.TOP)
win.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]